# How do I resolve this hilt error " Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'."?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

My fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LogsFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject private lateinit var logger: LoggerLocalDataSource
    @Inject private lateinit var dateFormatter: DateFormatter

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logs, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)     {
        recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
        }
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        logger.getAllLogs { logs ->
            recyclerView.adapter = LogsViewAdapter(logs, dateFormatter)
        }
    }
}
```

`RecyclerView.Adapter` for the logs list:

```
private class LogsViewAdapter(
    private val logsDataSet: List<Log>,
    private val daterFormatter: DateFormatter
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LogsViewAdapter.LogsViewHolder>() {

    class LogsViewHolder(val textView: TextView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LogsViewHolder {
        return LogsViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, parent, false) as TextView
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = logsDataSet.size

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LogsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val log = logsDataSet[position]
        holder.textView.text = "${log.msg}\n\t${daterFormatter.formatDate(log.timestamp)}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `private` modifier before the `lateinit`:

```
@Inject lateinit var logger: LoggerLocalDataSource
@Inject lateinit var dateFormatter: DateFormatter
```